# strange behavior of arr[-1] in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    printf("outside loop trail 1: arr[-1] = %d \n", arr[-1]);
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        printf("\ninside loop trail i = %d, arr[-1] = %d \n", i, arr[-1]);
    }
}
```

Question:

Why the output inside the loop is the sequence 0, 1, 2 (same as the loop index i); but the output outside the loop changes every time I execute the code? Thanks!

Output after

```
g++ -o explore explore.cpp && ./explore
```

outside loop trail 1: arr[-1] = 537839344

inside loop trail i = 0, arr[-1] = 0

inside loop trail i = 1, arr[-1] = 1

inside loop trail i = 2, arr[-1] = 2

run ./explore for a second time:

outside loop trail 1: arr[-1] = 1214220016

inside loop trail i = 0, arr[-1] = 0

inside loop trail i = 1, arr[-1] = 1

inside loop trail i = 2, arr[-1] = 2

Comment: arr[-1] is not a valid index, it's just random data that's sitting in memory next to your array.

Comment: Turns out undefined behavior yields undefined results.

Comment: There's no "why" here. The behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually covered in the standard. For example, `C++17 [expr.add] /4` states:

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the expression `P` points to element `x[i]` of an array object `x` with `n` elements, the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i + j]` if `0 <= i + j <= n`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The reason I'm discussing adding pointers and integers is because of the equivalence of `array[index]` and `*(array + index)`, as per `C++17 [expr.sub] /1` (that's `sub` as in subscripting, not subtraction):

> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`.

Now that's a lot to take in but it basically means that the result of adding a 'pointer to array element' and an 'index', gives you a pointer that is *required* to point to either an element in the array or just beyond the last one<sup>(1)</sup>.

Since a pointer *before* the first one (`array[-1]`) does *not* meet that requirement, it's undefined behaviour. Once you do that, all bets are off and the implementation is free to do what it likes. You can count yourself lucky it didn't erase your hard disk after playing `derisive_laughter.ogg` :-)

Note that there's nothing wrong per se with a negative index, the following code gives you the second element (the final "pointer" is still within the array):

```
int array[100];
int *ptrThird = &(array[2]);
int second = ptrThird[-1];
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that a *pointer* is allowed to point just beyond the array provided you don't try to dereference it. Unfortunately, `array[index]` *is* a dereferncing operation so, while `int array[10]; int *p = &(array[10]);` is valid, `int x = array[10];` is not.

Answer (score 2):

This is an undefined behavior.

Comment: Not sure why you are downvoted. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Well, there's "correct" and then there's "useful". I have to say that there's little difference between this answer and "the standard says you're not allowed to do that". Contrast with the answer from Kyle which provides more of an explanation as to *why* it's UB. I'd like to see the answers go even further and cite the relevant section of the standard.

Comment: @paxdiablo I'd accept that if Kyle actually mentioned it.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: granted. Kyle's could use some work as well.

Comment: It was mentioned plenty of times in the comments.  However, use of a negative index is often useful anyway.

Comment: @KyleHuff Never in the context of arr.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Right.  With arr in this example only 0,1,and 2 have defined behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, an array index used this way is equivalent to doing pointer math thusly:

```
arr[n] -> *(arr+n)
```

By using a negative index, you are referencing memory before the start of the memory block associated with the array data.  If you use an index that is outside the bounds of the array, the result is, as others have pointed out, *undefined*.

Comment: It's worth noting that while the above describes what probably *is* happening, anything *could* happen.  (i.e. once undefined behavior is invoked, all bets are off.  In particular, modern C++ optimizers aggressively refactor their internal representation of the program using algorithms that assume there will be no undefined behavior, so programs that do invoke undefined behavior can display very surprising/unintuitive behavior when run!)

Comment: Pointer math like this is guaranteed to work only within an array.  A pointer used for this may start out pointing to any element.  Hence, there's nothing wrong with using a negative index per se.

Answer (score 2):

[expr.sub/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#1):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of type “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type. The result is of type “T”. The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type. **The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))**, except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise. The expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2.

[expr.add/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.add-4):

> When an expression J that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression P of pointer type, the result has the type of P.
>   (4.1) If P evaluates to a null pointer value and J evaluates to 0, the result is a null pointer value.
>   (4.2) Otherwise, if P points to element x[i] of an array object x with n elements, the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element x[i + j] if  0 ≤ i + j ≤ n and the expression P - J points to the (possibly-hypothetical) element  x[i - j] if 0 ≤ i − j ≤ n.
>   (4.3) **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**